# Declaring Global Array in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, global-variables

I am trying speedup the processing/calculation in Google spreadsheet by putting my bonus setting into global array using PropertiesServices instead of loading the bonus % from the Setting sheet whenever user update their Daily sheet.

The method I used seem not working as I expected, the FOR loop is unable to look for "ALL". Hope someone able to give some advice.

I suspected that JSON structure is different from my 2D array, but I don't know how to solve it, I am new to javascripts.

Setting sheet only containing 4 columns: Game, StartDate, EndDate, Bonus %

p/s: This is a simplified scripts.

```
        function onOpen(event) {

        var bonusSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Setting");
        var bonusCompany = bonusSheet.getRange("A46:D503").getValues();

        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("bonusCompany", JSON.stringify(bonusCompany));
        }

        function onEdit(event) {
        var colGame = "H";
        var colBonus = "K";
        var numColBonus = 11;
        var nPoint;
        var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
        var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
        var col = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
        var cGame = sheet.getRange(colGame+row).getValue();
        var dDate = new Date();

        for(var k=0, kLen=bonusCompany.length; k<kLen; k++)
        {
        if((bonusCompany[k][0] == cGame || bonusCompany[k][0] == "ALL") && dDate.valueOf() >= bonusCompany[k][1] && dDate.valueOf() <= bonusCompany[k][2] ){
          sheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart,numColBonus,event.range.rowEnd-event.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(nPoint*bonusCompany[i][4]/100);
          return;}
        }
        sheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart,numColBonus,event.range.rowEnd-event.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(0);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()`, how about following sample script?

Your script is almost correct. When the data is set by `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty()`, the data can be retrieved by `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty()`. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.

And when the array data is set by `setProperty()`, the array data is stored as strings by `JSON.stringify()`. So it is necessary to convert from the string data to the array data. Fortunately, it has already known that the values retrieved by `getValues()` from spreadsheet is 2 dimensional array. So the string data can be converted to an array data using the regular expression. The sample script is as follows. I added 2 lines to your script. Please check them.

**Script :**

```
function onOpen(event) {
  var bonusSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Setting");
  var bonusCompany = bonusSheet.getRange("A46:D503").getValues();
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("bonusCompany", JSON.stringify(bonusCompany));
}

function onEdit(event) {
  var colGame = "H";
  var colBonus = "K";
  var numColBonus = 11;
  var nPoint;
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var col = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var cGame = sheet.getRange(colGame+row).getValue();
  var dDate = new Date();

  var d = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("bonusCompany").split(/^\[|\]$/)[1].split(/\[(.*?)\]/); // I added this line.
  var bonusCompany = [[(e=="\"\"" ? "" : e) for each (e in f)] for each (f in [d[j].split(",") for (j in d) if(j%2==1)])]; // I added this line.

  for(var k=0, kLen=bonusCompany.length; k<kLen; k++) {
    if((bonusCompany[k][0] == cGame || bonusCompany[k][0] == "ALL") && dDate.valueOf() >= bonusCompany[k][1] && dDate.valueOf() <= bonusCompany[k][2] ){
      sheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart,numColBonus,event.range.rowEnd-event.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(nPoint*bonusCompany[i][4]/100);
      return;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart,numColBonus,event.range.rowEnd-event.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(0);
}
```

I don't know data of your spreadsheet. So if this modification doesn't work, can I ask you about the data of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for your helps.

I have tested the method using propertiesServices to store the global arrays, the processing speed is even slower than using getValues() directly load from Setting sheet.
Maybe due to propertiesServices method is storing arrays as JSON string, and I need to restore JSON string back to arrays whenever users editing something.

It seem google-spreadsheet don't have global variable feature at the moment.

Comment: If the data size is less than 100 kbytes, you can use Cache Service. I proposed this sample, because I had thought that you want to use ``PropertiesService``. If you want sample code with cache service for your script, feel free to tell me. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/